# Compile Scss with Webpack

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack, bundle, frontend

I'm still trying to wrap my head around webpack, and coming from Gulp it's quite confusing. My project structure looks like:

```
./root
  -- src
    -- styles.scss
  -- bin
  -- node_modules
  -- webpack.config.js
```

So just something super simple, I want to compile the `styles.scss` in the `src` directory and output it to the `bin` directory. I installed the following loaders:

- style-loader
- css-loader
- sass-loader (also installed `node_sass` as a dependency)

Now I know I'm not grasping something very fundamental of Webpack here but here's my **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/styles.scss',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'styles.css'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack` in the root of my directory it *looks* like it works. But the `styles.css` file looks like it contains a bunch of JavaScript code. So I don't understand that and need some clarity. I'm vaguely guessing that you can't use webpack if you don't have any JavaScript files in your project (besides `webpack.config.js` of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am by far no webpack expert, but to my understanding, this is exactly what webpack is supposed to do, according to it's own documentation:

> **Loaders**
>
> webpack can only process JavaScript natively, but loaders are used to
> transform other resources into JavaScript. [...]

What this means is, even if you only include SCSS-Files, webpack will convert them into a JavaScript-File, which can then be included just like any other JS-File.

For example, if you changed your `styles.css` into `styles.js`, you would call it in the head of html with

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="application/javascript" src="styles.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

Despite this, your CSS, although called as and wrapped in JavaScript, will still be correctly treated as CSS.

#### Why would you want to do this?

Basically to save calls to the server.
Webpack gives you the opportunity, to bundle your JS, your [S]CSS and [many other things](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html) into a single JS-File, which you will be able to fetch with a single call to the server, therefore saving lots of round-trip-times.
Still, the browser will interpret all the resources accordingly.

Comment: Wow! I think that finally made me grasp Webpack! That's pretty amazing actually.. As a side note though. If Webpack only bundles everything into a single js file. How would you move your index.html from your 'src' directory into your 'bin' directory with Webpack?

Comment: You wouldn't do that with webpack. You need some html-file that includes your bundled JS-file. If you want to have a minimalistic `index.html`, you can use the according [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader)